# Can I use the code for the sample in this page in my App

Tags: android

Can I use the code for the sample in this page in my App?

Sample page link:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Please extend your question. What do you want to achieve and how is the question relevant. What have you tried so far etc.

Comment: like change the images path to my images and change the App name and some other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.. if for personal use, sure .. if for Google Play you would have to do more than that.

But it can of course be part of your app, it is official developer tutorials from Google, which is meant to be adapted as good practice in apps.

Then it would not make sense to disallow usage.